# How to use Java 8 Stream API without collect method?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a problem to solve where I should find the nth Employee  whose gender is Male from a list of Employees using java 8 streams, if nothing found return Optional empty.

```
class Employee{
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String gender;
   
  //getters and setters
}
```

Below is the method which accepts a list of Employee objects and integer n where n denotes the nth male employee that has to be returned if exists.

```
Optional<Employee> nthMaleEmployee(List<Employee> employees, int n){

}
```

Below is my solution for the question using java 8 streams and collect method.

```
return employees.stream().filter((e)-> e.getGender().equalsIgnoreCase("male")).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(n-1);
```

Is there any solution with streams not using collect method? My problem statement is to use streams without using collect method.

Comment: Get familiar with skip and findFirst methods on a stream. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long- and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Also, rethink if you want n to be zero or one based. Java programmers expect indices to be zero-based.

Comment: Lesiak 0 based or 1 based has no bearing on the ordinal selection of a list. If you want the `8th` one,`n` should be`8` regardless so one should `skip(n-1)`

Comment: @WJS The opposite is true. If you skip `n-1` it looks like the index is 1 based. If you skip `n`, it looks like the index is 0 based. I expect a parameter `n` in the original signature `nthMaleEmployee(List<Employee> employees, int n)` to behave like zero-based index, so skipping `n` is needed to achieve that.

Comment: @Lesiak When you call `nthMaleEmployee(list, n)`.  Even the method name says `nth`  If you want the 8th value, you need to skip 7.  The ordinal of an array is completely independent of its base and how many you skip.  If the arrays were `5` based you would still say 8 for the 8th and skip 7.  `n` is not the index of the value to get.  In a java array, array[0] is the 1st value and array[1] is the 2nd value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the skip method to skip (n-1) elements in the list and findFirst method would give you the nth element.